# How do I tell if my HP laptop has the built-in Contexant keylogger?

Tags: laptop, security, keylogger

Links to: **[Security hole report](https://www.modzero.ch/advisories/MZ-17-01-Conexant-Keylogger.txt)** and **[article](http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/hp-audio-driver-laptop-keylogger.html)**.

Quote from the security report:

> the following systems are affected:
>   *   HP EliteBook 820 G3 Notebook PC
>   *  HP EliteBook 828 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 840 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 848 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 850 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 640 G2 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 650 G2 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 645 G2 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 655 G2 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 450 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 430 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 440 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 446 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 470 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ProBook 455 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 725 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 745 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 755 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP EliteBook 1030 G1 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ZBook 15u G3 Mobile Workstation
>   *   HP Elite x2 1012 G1 Tablet
>   *   HP Elite x2 1012 G1 with Travel Keyboard
>   *   HP Elite x2 1012 G1 Advanced Keyboard
>   *   HP EliteBook Folio 1040 G3 Notebook PC
>   *   HP ZBook 17 G3 Mobile Workstation
>   *   HP ZBook 15 G3 Mobile Workstation
>   *   HP ZBook Studio G3 Mobile Workstation
>   *   HP EliteBook Folio G1 Notebook PC

I note that all those have a series name (Elite, ZBook, etc), and so do almost all the laptops listed in [Wikipedia's "List of HP products" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hewlett-Packard_products).

[The page for my laptop](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/c04933701) lists just `HP Notebook - 15-ac107nu (ENERGY STAR)` as product name and `P1E10EA` as product number. Since that product name is not listed in Wikipedia, I guess my laptop may actually have a series name too, omitted from the HP page for my laptop.

So my question is: how do I tell if my HP laptop has that built-in security hole?

Comment: First check if you even have the application in question, then check if you have the audio device in question, then conclude if your laptop is vulnerable by the answers to those questions.  You haven't provided the information required for us to tell if your vulnerable to the vulnerability or not with the information you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by verifying if either

```
C:\Windows\System32\MicTray64.exe
```

or

```
C:\Windows\System32\MicTray.exe
```

is installed.

If it is installed in your system, it'll log keystrokes in the file

```
C:\Users\Public\MicTray.log
```

Note that Windows Defender now detects and removes this threat: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=MonitoringTool:Win32/MicTrayDebugger . A correct version of the Conexant HD Audio Driver (without keylogger!) will then be installed automatically via Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have a Conexant audio controller (look in your Device Manager)?
2. Are you using a version of the driver that's mentioned in the article (=< 1.0.0.46)?

If you answered No to either of those then you don't have the affected driver software installed.